# Finding the recurrence relation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

So the question has 2 parts to it.

Let $f(n)$ be  the number of sequences in length n that are built of 0, 1, and 2, so that after zero there's always 1 right after it.

Let $g(n)$ be the number of sequences in length n that are built of 0, 1 and 2, so that between two 2's in the sequence theres 0. (not necessarily right after it)

I need to find recurrence relations for $f(n)$ and $g(n)$.

I need some hints or ideas, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested here is an alternative solution for $g$:

We call the sequences with the requested property *g-sequences*.
Furthermore, we call a sequence *X-sequence* if adding a symbol 2 in the end yields a g-sequence. Obviously, any X-sequence is a g-sequence too.
Let $X(n)$ be the number of X-sequences of length $n$.

If the last symbol of a g-sequence is 0 or 1, the remaining part is an arbitrary g-sequence.
If the last symbol is 2, the remaining part is an arbitrary X-sequence.
So
$$g(n) = 2g(n-1) + X(n-1).$$

An X-sequence cannot end on the symbol 2.
If the last symbol of a X-sequence is 0, then the remaining part is an arbitrary g-sequence. (But not necessarily a X-sequence, look for example at the sequence 20.)
If the last symbol of a X-sequence is 1, then the remaining part is an arbitrary X-sequence. So
$$X(n) = g(n-1) + X(n-1).$$

Iterated replacement of the expressions $X(i)$ in the recursion for $g(n)$ yields the recursion formula of the other answer (involving the summation).

Comment: Why is $X_n = g (n-1)+ X_{n-1}??

Comment: @YvesHalimi I've extended the answer.

Comment: I've read it a few doZen times and I got it eventually :) thanks!  How do I solve g(n)?

Comment: To get a full expression of g(n) , I tried to guess a few Solutions and to prove with induction , but i think they all fail. Is there a standart way of solving that recurrence relation?

Comment: hey azimut, are you still here?

Comment: @YvesHalimi There is a standard method using linear algebra. Write $\begin{pmatrix}g(n)\\X(n)\end{pmatrix} = A\begin{pmatrix}g(n-1)\\X(n-1)\end{pmatrix}$ with a suitable matrix $A$ and compute $A^n$. Anyway, this discussion was about finding a recurrence relation, so you should open a new question for it.

Comment: I will, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For $f$: If the first digit is a 0, then necessarily the second one is a 1. The remaining part is an arbitrary legitimate sequence of length $n-2$.
If the first digit is a 1 or a 2, the remaining part is an arbitrary legitimate sequence of length $n-1$. So
$$
f(n) = 2f(n-1) + f(n-2).
$$
with
$$
f(0) = 1 \quad\text{and}\quad f(1) = 3.
$$

For $g$: If the first digit is a 0 or a 1, then the remaining part is an arbitrary legitimate sequence of length $n-1$.
If the first digit is a 2, then the remaining part must have the form
$$
\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n-1\text{ times}}
$$
or
$$
\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{i\text{ times}}0 s
$$
where $i\in\{0,\ldots,n-2\}$ and $s$ is a legitimate sequence of length $n-i-2$.
So
$$
g(n) = 2g(n-1) + 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} g(n-2-i)
= 2g(n-1) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} g(i) + 1.
$$
with
$$
g(0) = 1.
$$

Comment: I need to bound: $f(n) \ge {(2{1 \over 3})}^{n}$, how do I do it?

Comment: @YvesHalimi: Induction

Comment: Thanks, i did it :) I think i figured that i can bound $f_n$ between $2^{1 \over k}$ where k is as large as i want, i dont understand how could it be?

Comment: I don't understand what u did there for $g(n)$.
the hint that they give in the books is: "Set $X_n$ to be the number of sequences of length n , that if u add it 2 at the end , it is still a legitimate sequence of size n+1" What do the hint means? that $X_n = a_n +1$? and then finding $X_n$ is easier?

Comment: how did u exatcly build the sum?

Comment: @YvesHalimi: The sum results from the different possibilities for $i\in\{0,\ldots,n-2\}$.

Comment: what about the connection between $X_n$ and $a_n$? Which is it?

Comment: are you still here? Should I re-ask in a different post?